# How to matching sequential words in a sentence using Perl?

Tags: perl

Is there better way to match words other than this method, im trying to find the word in the array that occur in any of the sentences.

```
 my $count = 0;
 my @strings = (
    "i'm going to find the occurrence of two words going if possible",
    "i'm going to find the occurrence of two words if impossible",
    "to find a solution to this problem",
    "i will try my best for a way to match this problem"
 );
 @neurot = qw(going match possible);

 my $com_neu = '\b'.join('\b|\b', @neurot).'\b';

 foreach my $sentence (@string){

 @l = $sentence =~ /($com_neu)/gi; 

 foreach my $list (@l){ 
    if($list =~ m/\w['\w-]*/){
          print $list;
      $count++;
    }   
 }

 print $count;
 }
```

Output:

```
String 1: going going possible
String 2: going 
String 3:
String 4: match
```

please help me with a faster way.

Thanks.

Comment: For starters, you don't need `\b` around every word, just around the parens: `\b($com_neu)\b`.

Comment: You should probably provide some more information about your data and sentences (how many words in `@neurot`, how long sentences, ...).

Comment: m/\w/ will match all the same strings as m/\w['\w-]*/ will. So what is the point of the ['\w-]* part?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to use hash to match the words:

```
my %neurot_hash = map { lc($_) => 1 } qw(going match possible);

for my $sentence (@strings) {
    for my $found (grep { $neurot_hash{ lc($_) } } $sentence =~ /\w['\w-]*/gi) {
        print $found, " ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

For data you provided this method is ~ 7% faster. But keep in mind that the data set is very small, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

what about the 'smart-match' operator?

`foreach my $elem (@neurot){
    if(/$elem/i ~~ @strings){
        print "Found $elem\n";
    }
}`

Comment: This makes impossible to tell what string contains what element, to say nothing about count. Also, if `@neurot` is kind of dictionary, this could be quite ineffective.

Comment: @bvr: you are right `@neurot` is are dictionary, it is going be ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

The same as bvr answer, but perhaps cleaner

```
my %neurot_hash = map { lc($_) => 1 } qw(going match possible);

for my $sentence (@strings) {
    my @words = split /[^\w']/, $sentence; 
            #I am not sure if you want to take "i'm" as a separate word. 
            #Apparently, stackoverflow does not like '.

    my @found = grep { exists $neurot_hash{ lc($_) } } @words;
    print join (" ",  @found);
    print "\n";
}
```